# How to select columns that only have positive values?

Tags: python, pandas

Given pandas data frame `df`, I need to select those columns that only have positive values.

```
df =
  Age    Fare     Dev
  21     10        -1
  35     9        0
  28     12       1
```

My first idea was to use `df.describe()` and then select only those columns that have minimum value greater or equal to 0.
But I got stuck with the implementation. Apparently `row.columns` does not work, because Series does not have `columns` property.

```
properties = df.describe()
positive_cols = []
for index,row in properties.iterrows():
    for col in row.columns:
        print(col)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) (`>=`) for compare `DataFrame`. Then get boolean mask with all `True`s by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and last use `loc`, because filtering columns:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.ge(0).all()]
print (df)
   Age  Fare
0   21    10
1   35     9
2   28    12
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.ge(0))
    Age  Fare    Dev
0  True  True  False
1  True  True  False
2  True  True   True

print (df.ge(0).all())
Age      True
Fare     True
Dev     False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: So elegant. Thanks.

Comment: OP's need minimum value greater or equal to 0, I suggest to use `ge`.